# Can a menstruating women prepare food for herself?

Tags: scripture, women, menstruation

It is well-known that a rajaswala cannot prepare food for her family. It is highly discouraged to eat food prepared by a Rajaswala.

But, does it apply to herself also? Can't she cook for herself and eat it?

Comment: No. She cannot go near Agni. Family members have to cook & feed her. So she can have fruits/nuts etc. without cooking. That's why in olden days, husbands knew how to cook. Wives do it 27 days in a month, husband 3 days. She gets complete rest. Of course, she has other restrictions like not touching anyone, not bathing etc. but not many people want to follow that nowadays citing "invention of sanitary napkins solved hygiene issue". It's not like olden days people were roaming like animals. They had cloth rags instead of pads. It's not about physical hygiene, but spiritual/ritual/Achara hygiene.